How to know the difference between a java file on fields and methods under two save operations?
Changes to a java file can be known by method org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.addElementChangedListener(IElementChangedListener).
There's this scenario:

primitive code:

public class X {

}


Add a new field a

public class X {
    int a ;
}


Receives an event POST_RECONCILE saying that a new element a has been added.

Add a new field b


public class X {
    int a ;
    int b ;
}


Receives an event POST_RECONCILE saying that a new element b has been added.

Remove the field b


public class X {
    int a ;
}


Receives an event POST_RECONCILE saying that a new element b has been removed.

Save this file.

Receives an event POST_CHANGE saying that the element X has been changed.


My intention is to know what has changed in that file between two save operations, as in the above scenario where element a is added, not necessary to know that element b.
However, this doesn't seem to be possible if I'm only listening to the POST_CHANGE event, and if I'm also listening to the POST_RECONCILE event, it seems to require a lot of checking and judging on my part.
Is there a simpler way to do this?
